# How to correctly use play2 with maven, play2-maven-plugin and IDEA?

Tags: scala, maven, intellij-idea, playframework

I setup a play2 project with Maven like in [this example](https://github.com/orrsella/play-maven-integration), adapted to Play 2.4 as per the official documentation of the [play2-maven-plugin](https://code.google.com/p/play2-maven-plugin/wiki/UsagePlay24). I am using IntelliJ IDEA.

Now I have a simple controller:

```
object FooController extends Controller {
  val foo = Action {
    Ok("foo")
  }

  val bar = Action {
    Redirect(routes.FooController.foo())
  }
}
```

my `routes` file contains:

```
GET /foo    controllers.FooController.foo
GET /bar    controllers.FooController.bar
```

Now, I ran into several problems.

The first problem was `FooController` not finding `routes`. I had to manually do `mvn play2:routes-compile` on the command line to have the routes generated, but they are in an excluded directory named `target/src_managed/main`. To get them in scope, I have to use the `build-helper-maven-plugin` like so:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
    <artifactId>build-helper-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>${build-helper-maven-plugin.version}</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <phase>process-sources</phase>
            <goals><goal>add-source</goal></goals>
            <configuration>
                <sources>
                    <source>${project.build.directory}/src_managed/main</source>
                </sources>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

The routes work after I do `mvn clean play2:routes-compile` again, and IDEA shows no errors. However, I must avoid touching the managed sources folder, and avoid opening any generated source files in there, even only for looking at them, because there will be other reference problems which are really not there, but they are there because IDEA does not figure out it is a Play2 project. When doing a `mvn package play2:run` on the command line, the application starts and works as expected.

Unfortunately, I currently must use Maven because it is a big Maven project with many submodules I cannot change to SBT in a few hours/days.

So, is there any advice on how to correctly use this and get IDEA to recognize my project as Play2? Is it possible to auto-run the `play2:resources-compile` goal when I select `Build/Rebuild Project` or `Make module`?

Answer (score 1):

Use one of [example projects](http://play2-maven-plugin.googlecode.com/svn/tags/test-projects-1.0.0-beta1/play23/) instead of [this](https://github.com/orrsella/play-maven-integration).

I use ScalaIDE, but I've tested Idea integration and it works. Import Maven project, add Scala support, rebuild.

Comment: I checked my project against your multimodule example, and indeed my pom for the play module looks nearly identical, the only thing different is that I have the `build-helper-maven-plugin` which adds the `src_managed/main` folder as a source folder and the explicit specification of `routes-compile` in the `generate-sources` phase. I think this is an issue with IDEA. Since I plan to switch to sbt in the near future, I can live with it for now.

Comment: I've just created wiki page about [IDEA integration](https://code.google.com/p/play2-maven-plugin/wiki/IDEAIntegration)

Comment: `play2` packaging is responsible for adding `target/src_managed/main` directory as additional sources root. You can remove `build-helper-maven-plugin`.