# How to customize dist by using play2-maven plugin for play project?

Tags: scala, maven, playframework

I am using [play2-maven-plugin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29917155/how-to-correctly-use-play2-with-maven-play2-maven-plugin-and-idea/33868585#33868585). I am creating dist, when I generate dist I am able to see lib folder containing all jars, **build.properties** and **start.bat** file. My project have some extra script files and few conf folder which I need to be get in dist when we create dist file; But I am not getting way to add those in **dist.zip**.

Can you please guide how I can generate dist with all my required files?